# Using JAXB to unmarshal xml file

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, jaxb

I need to parse the content of an [archetype-catalog.xml](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-catalog/archetype-catalog.html) file to a Java Object structure. For this I thought I'll use good old `JAXB`. So, i looked for the [xsd](http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-catalog-1.0.0.xsd) definition of the xml file and generated the jaxb classes out of it:

ArchetypeCatalog.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 *  0.0.0+
 * 
 * <p>Java class for ArchetypeCatalog complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="ArchetypeCatalog">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;all>
 *         &lt;element name="archetypes" minOccurs="0">
 *           &lt;complexType>
 *             &lt;complexContent>
 *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                 &lt;sequence>
 *                   &lt;element name="archetype" type="{http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0}Archetype" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
 *                 &lt;/sequence>
 *               &lt;/restriction>
 *             &lt;/complexContent>
 *           &lt;/complexType>
 *         &lt;/element>
 *       &lt;/all>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ArchetypeCatalog", propOrder = {

})
public class ArchetypeCatalog {

    protected ArchetypeCatalog.Archetypes archetypes;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the archetypes property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link ArchetypeCatalog.Archetypes }
     *     
     */
    public ArchetypeCatalog.Archetypes getArchetypes() {
        return archetypes;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the archetypes property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link ArchetypeCatalog.Archetypes }
     *     
     */
    public void setArchetypes(ArchetypeCatalog.Archetypes value) {
        this.archetypes = value;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;element name="archetype" type="{http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0}Archetype" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "archetype"
    })
    public static class Archetypes {

        protected List<Archetype> archetype;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the archetype property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
         * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
         * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
         * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the archetype property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
         * <pre>
         *    getArchetype().add(newItem);
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         * <p>
         * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
         * {@link Archetype }
         * 
         * 
         */
        public List<Archetype> getArchetype() {
            if (archetype == null) {
                archetype = new ArrayList<Archetype>();
            }
            return this.archetype;
        }

    }

}
```

Archetype.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * 
 *              Informations to point to an Archetype referenced in the catalog.
 *          
 * 
 * <p>Java class for Archetype complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="Archetype">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;all>
 *         &lt;element name="groupId" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="artifactId" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="version" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="repository" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="description" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/all>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Archetype", propOrder = {

})
public class Archetype {

    protected String groupId;
    protected String artifactId;
    protected String version;
    protected String repository;
    protected String description;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the groupId property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the groupId property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setGroupId(String value) {
        this.groupId = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the artifactId property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getArtifactId() {
        return artifactId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the artifactId property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setArtifactId(String value) {
        this.artifactId = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the version property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the version property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setVersion(String value) {
        this.version = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the repository property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getRepository() {
        return repository;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the repository property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setRepository(String value) {
        this.repository = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the description property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the description property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setDescription(String value) {
        this.description = value;
    }

}
```

ObjectFactory.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _ArchetypeCatalog_QNAME = new QName("http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0", "archetype-catalog");


    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link ArchetypeCatalog }
     * 
     */
    public ArchetypeCatalog createArchetypeCatalog() {
        return new ArchetypeCatalog();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link Archetype }
     * 
     */
    public Archetype createArchetype() {
        return new Archetype();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link ArchetypeCatalog.Archetypes }
     * 
     */
    public ArchetypeCatalog.Archetypes createArchetypeCatalogArchetypes() {
        return new ArchetypeCatalog.Archetypes();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link ArchetypeCatalog }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0", name = "archetype-catalog")
    public JAXBElement<ArchetypeCatalog> createArchetypeCatalog(ArchetypeCatalog value) {
        return new JAXBElement<ArchetypeCatalog>(_ArchetypeCatalog_QNAME, ArchetypeCatalog.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

However when actually unmashalling the [example](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-catalog/archetype-catalog.html) file for testing, I get the following:

StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: an error occurred while unmarshalling xml into com.catalogupdater.plugin.jaxb.ArchetypeCatalog object
    at com.catalogupdater.plugin.converter.JAXBConverter.stringToObject(JAXBConverter.java:48)
    at Main.main(Main.java:60)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0", local:"archetype-catalog"). Expected elements are (none)
```

Any suggestion what's going wrong here?
kind regards

**EDIT**:
Below is the full unmarshalling logic I am using:

```
   public static <T> T stringToObject( final String textClazz, final Class<T> clazz )
   {
      T returnedValue = null;
      try
      {
         final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( clazz );
         final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
         final StringReader reader = new StringReader( textClazz );
         returnedValue = ( T ) unmarshaller.unmarshal( reader );
      }
      catch ( final JAXBException e )
      {
         throw new RuntimeException(
               "an error occurred while unmarshalling xml into " + clazz.getCanonicalName() + " object", e );
      }
      return returnedValue;
   }
```

Comment: Show your complete unmarshalling code.

Comment: @lexicore  Hi, I've edited the question

Comment: Somehow your `ObjectFactory` is not used. Try to create `JAXBContext` with the package name (`clazz.getPackage().getName()`).

Comment: @lexicore when I do this, the stringToObject Method will produce an object of type `javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement` which I cannot cast then to `ArchetypeCatalog` as I want ...

Comment: You just have to `getValue()` if it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out that there was the following `@RootElement`Annotation missing in the generated `ArchetypeCatalog` class:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0", name = "archetype-catalog")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ArchetypeCatalog", propOrder = {

})
public class ArchetypeCatalog
{

 ...
}
```

I've added it manually, now it works fine. Don't know why this was not generated. Nevertheless, After all I think generating classes from `xsd` specification needs to be treated with caution.

kind regards

**EDIT**: as @ulab stated in the comments, the reason for the missing `@RootElement` is given [here](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/kohsuke/2006/03/03/why-does-jaxb-put-xmlrootelement-sometimes-not-always).

**EDIT**: Also, it is not neccessary or not advisable to put the `@XMLRootElement` annotation manually. More details can be found in the answer written by @lexicor.

Comment: now you know [why](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/kohsuke/2006/03/03/why-does-jaxb-put-xmlrootelement-sometimes-not-always)

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like:

```
     final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( clazz.getPackage().getName() );
     final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
     final StringReader reader = new StringReader( textClazz );
     returnedValue = ( T ) unmarshaller.unmarshal( reader ).getValue();
```

Apparently if you just create `JAXBContext` of your `clazz`, the `ObjectFactory` is not considered. `ObjectFactory` is a so-called "XML registry" which says which class should be used for which root element.

What you get from unmarshalling is `JAXBContext<SomeType>` which contains both the value of type `SomeType` (`ArchetypeCatalog` in your case) as well as the name of the root element. You can get the value you're interested in via `getValue()`.

What you did in your answer also works but that's not the "JAXB way" of doing that.

You've added the `@XmlRootElement` annotation manually which is surely not good for generated code. You can add it via plugin like `jaxb2-annotate-plugin` (disclaimer: I'm the author).

But ultimately you should better use `ObjectFactory` as it is what it's for. You'll be better off long-term sticking to the standard patterns.

Comment: This is then of course the better solution and the right answer. I've tried your suggestion and it worked. For the other direction (marshalling) however it did not work properly, saying that there is a missing @RootElement annotation. I figured out that I had to use the `ObjectFactory` which will wrap the the root class into an JAXBElement with the required information. This worked also. However i noticed that the xsi:schemaLocation was missing in the generated xml. Do you have any suggestion how to also achieve this (besides adding the schemalocation manually, as i do it for now)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to check first that the versions of both the XJC for the generation of the classes and the version of the libraries with which it is being executed are the same. The same thing happened to me and it was enough to guarantee that both versions were the same.
You can see this information in the initial comment of the generated classes and in the versions of the libraries that you use for their execution.